# MVC JS Member not Found when submitting

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, model-view-controller

I try to submit a form after I do a validation from the JS and i get the error in developer mode Member Not Found at the line with `.submit`.

This is how I declared the form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "spc_form" }))
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

And this is the code:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" class="btn btn-warning" id="submit" /> 
<input type="button" value="Save" class="btn btn-warning" id="save" />




    $('#save').click(function () {
        var validated = 1;
        //input black borders here

        if ($('#multi_project_name_0').val() == "" || $('#multi_project_name_0').val() == " ") {
            $('#multi_project_name_0').css("border-color", "red");
            validated = 0;
        }
        var x = document.getElementById("multi_pj_class").getElementsByTagName("tr").length;

        if (validated == 1) {
            if (document.getElementById("multi_sop").value == "" || document.getElementById("multi_sop").value == " ") {
                document.getElementById("multi_sop").value = document.getElementById("this_date").value;
            }
            if (document.getElementById("multi_start_pj").value == "" || document.getElementById("multi_start_pj").value == " ") {
                document.getElementById("multi_start_pj").value = document.getElementById("this_date").value;
            }
            if (document.getElementById("multi_date_evaluation").value == "" || document.getElementById("multi_date_evaluation").value == " ") {
                document.getElementById("multi_date_evaluation").value = document.getElementById("this_date").value;
            }
            for (var i = 1; i < x - 1; i++) {
                if (document.getElementById("multi_sop_" + i).value == "" || document.getElementById("multi_sop_" + i).value == " ") {
                    document.getElementById("multi_sop_" + i).value = document.getElementById("this_date").value;
                }
                if (document.getElementById("multi_start_pj_" + i).value == "" || document.getElementById("multi_start_pj_" + i).value == " ") {
                    document.getElementById("multi_start_pj_" + i).value = document.getElementById("this_date").value;
                }
            }
            document.getElementById("active").value = "2";
            document.getElementById("spc_form").submit(); <------ THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS
        }
        else {
            alert("You must complete the first Project Name field in order to save the project.");
            topFunction();
        }
    });
</script>
<!-------------------------------------->
```

Comment: can you post the html please?

Comment: I'd like to but there are like 900 lines of code :\

Comment: Is that form 900 lines of code? If so, you'll have to simplify it to get an answer on here.  Also MVC has built in ModelState validation which is better than using JS since it's client side.

Comment: Yeah the form alone is that big. I know it has but later our validation must be customized in a way. I think it'll take a lot to simplify it so I'll just hope someone got this problem on any kind of small or big form before and knows a tip :\

Comment: I think your best bet will be setting a breakpoint at the submit line and make sure your object looks like what your controller is expecting.

Comment: I think you need to check your HTML if there are duplicated Id or names. Hope this will help.